# Long Messages in Kafka: Persistence and Retention

Tags: java, apache-kafka, persistence

I am designing a project based on Kafka. In this project messages have a payload whose **size  can reach 4Mb to 10Mb** (this is what I considered as *long messages*)

*I know it is possible to configure Kafka so that it accept such messages but I also know that it is **not recommended** and that it would decrease the overall performance*

I would prefer to **persist the payload of my messages**... for the moment I don't know in what, it could be in a Database *(Sybase, Hadoop, ...)*, on the FileSystem *(Webdav, ...)* or anything else

The payload of my messages would only contain a way to access the data in the persistence system *(it could be a SQL query, or a URL, a path...)*

---

I found this way of doing rather elegant and perfectly suited to the requirements of my project until I realized that it will also **have to delete the long data from the persistence system** once there are no more messages referencing it

> I other words:
>
> - when a message reaches the limit of its retention policy, **Kafka may remove it from its topic**.
> - if the message was referencing data in the persistence system, the data **may not be accessible anymore**
> - so it **could/should be removed**

My question is about the best way to do it? I guess I am not the first one to get this situation and I would like to know the solutions available to solve it:

- is there a way to synchronize the Broker with a Persistence system?
- or is there a way to get messages that were "removed" from a topic?
- or any other solution?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You could keep a "last updated" timestamp together with your data in the database, and then have a job delete expired data once in a while. The expiration time should be at least as long as the retention time on Kafka.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have such a solution in mind but my problem is that the "the job" becomes more and more complex when the message is used in many topics, having different retentions

Writing such a job is of course possible but I wanted to know if there were "best practices" for my problem or if there were tools on which I can rely.

Once again, thank you

Comment: You could create the expiration date early and send it with the event on Kafka. Then that expiration date could be propagated to all other topics as well. Each consumer would then need to check the expiration date of the link before trying to fetch the data.

Comment: You cannot target a single message to delete in a Kafka topic. If that is your goal, then you shouldn't persist those events in Kafka. Use a different message-queue like SNS that sends only one notification (that is not persistent after sent/consumed), then distribute that deletion event to all systems that do store the data